# Windows7 crashes when i run even simple Helloworld Android App through emulator of ADT plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: android

I downloaded the Android SDK from developers.android.com.My laptop has: 2 GB RAM,32 bit Windows7 operating system.Starting the emulator through command-line did not help.Please provide me solution.I'm using Android 4.2.2

Comment: Make sure you are running all Windows updates and the latest version of your display driver.

Comment: Which emulator are you using ? Some of the default settings are too large for windows e.g. 768MB memory max. You may need to shut down other programs and reduce the emulator memory allocation.

Comment: Hi Sheldon,I've pretty much tried all the emulators reducing RAM size.Also, I've tried running the emulator keeping all other programs closed.The laptop still crashed.